# uiautomator click/revoke application permission list

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I am trying to use uiautomator to revoke my application permissions in application details using [Google's sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/tree/master/ui/uiautomator/BasicSample). However, I ran into issue that my uiautomator seems getting the wrong status of toggle. When the toggle is checked, for some reasons, uiautomator still return me `false`.

My end goal is to toggle the buttons one by one from the same layouts with different index.

[image]

```
@Test
public void clickThruSettings() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {

// go to the target page and open the permissions list.
    Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();
    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", BASIC_SAMPLE_PACKAGE, null);
    intent.setData(uri);
    context.startActivity(intent);
    UiObject permissions = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text("Permissions"));
    permissions.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();

// toggle on and off with index for linearLayout.
    togglePermissionButton(true,0);  
    togglePermissionButton(false,1);
    togglePermissionButton(true,2);
    togglePermissionButton(false,3);
   }

 private void togglePermissionButton(boolean enabled, int index) throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
     UiObject permissionButton = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.LinearLayout")
             .scrollable(false).index(index)).getChild(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.Switch.class
             .getName()));
     if (permissionButton.waitForExists(2000)&& permissionButton.exists()&& permissionButton.isEnabled()) {
         if (permissionButton.isChecked() != enabled) {
             permissionButton.click();
         }
     }
 }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

index is based on its parent, cannot used like this.
you can directly find the switch with the instance property.

```
mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.Switch.class.getName()).instance(index));
```